# Fastest way to find most similar string to an input?

Tags: algorithm, string, language-agnostic

Given a query string Q of length N, and a list L of M sequences of length exactly N, what is the most efficient algorithm to find the string in L with the fewest mismatch positions to Q?  For example:

```
Q = "ABCDEFG";
L = ["ABCCEFG", "AAAAAAA", "TTAGGGT", "ZYXWVUT"];
answer = L.query(Q);  # Returns "ABCCEFG"
answer2 = L.query("AAAATAA");  #Returns "AAAAAAA".
```

The obvious way is to scan every sequence in L, making the search take O(M * N).  Is there any way to do this in sublinear time?  I don't care if there's a large upfront cost to organizing L into some data structure because it will be queried a lot of times.  Also, handling tied scores arbitrarily is fine.

Edit:  To clarify, I am looking for the Hamming distance.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861718/string-comparison-with-the-most-similar-string

Answer (score 11):

All the answers except the one that mentions the best first algorithm are very much off.
Locally sensitive hashing is basically dreaming. This is the first time I see answers so much off on stackoverflow.

First, this is a hard, but standard problem that has been solved many years ago 
in different ways.

One approach uses a trie such as the one preseted
by Sedgewick here:

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/strings/

Sedgewick also has sample C code.

I quote from the paper titled "Fast Algorithms for Sorting and Searching Strings" by Bentley and Sedgewick:

"‘‘Near neighbor’’ queries **locate all words within a given Hamming distance
of a query word** (for instance, code is distance 2 from soda). We give a new algorithm for near neighbor searching in strings, present a simple C implementation, and describe experiments on its efficiency."

A second approach is to use indexing. Split the strings into characters n-grams and index
with inverted index (google for Lucene spell checker to see how it's done). 
Use the index to pull potential candidates and then run hamming distance or edit distnace on the candidates. This is the approach guaranteed to work best (and relatively simple).

A third appears in the area of speech recognition. There the query is a wav signal, and the database is a set of strings. There is a "table" that matches pieces of the signal to pieces of words. The goal is to find the best match of words to signal. This problem is known as word alignment.

In the problem posted, there is an implicit cost of matching query parts to database parts.
For example one may have different costs for deletion/insertion/substitution and even
different costs for mismatching say "ph" with "f".

The standard solution in speech recognition uses a dynamic programming approach which is made efficient via heuristics that direct pruning. In this way, only the best, say 50 candidates are kept. Thus, the name best-first search. In theory, you may not get the best match, but usually one gets a good match.

Here is a reference to the latter approach:

http://amta2010.amtaweb.org/AMTA/papers/2-02-KoehnSenellart.pdf

Fast Approximate String Matching with Suffix Arrays and A* Parsing.

This approach applies not only to words but to sentences.

Answer (score 4):

[Locality sensitive hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_sensitive_hashing) underlies what seems to be the asymptotically best method known, as I understand it from this [review article in CACM](http://mags.acm.org/communications/200801/?searchterm=nearest+neighbor+in+high+dimensions&pg=119). Said article is pretty hairy and I didn't read it all. See also [nearest neighbor search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).

To relate these references to your problem: they all deal with a set of points in a metric space, such as an n-dimensional vector space. In your problem, n is the length of each string, and the values on each coordinate are the characters that can appear at each position in a string.

Answer (score 2):

The "best" method will vary significantly depending on your input set and query set. Having a  fixed message length will let you treat this problem in a classification context.

An information theoretic decision tree algorithm (like C4.5, for example) will provide the best overall guarantee on performance.  In order to get optimal performance out of this method, you must first cluster the string indices into features based on mutual information.  Note that you will need to modify the classifier to return all leaf nodes at the last branch, then compute a partial edit distance for each of them.  The edit distance only needs to be calculated for the feature set represented by the last split of the tree.

Using this technique, querying should be ~ O(k log n), k << m, where k is the expectation of the feature size, m is the length of the string, and n is the number of comparison sequences.

The initial setup on this is guaranteed to be less than O(m^2 + n*t^2), t < m, t * k ~ m, where t is the feature count for an item.  This is very reasonable and should not require any serious hardware.

These very nice performance numbers are possible because of the fixed m constraint.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [Levenshtein edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

There are a [few questions here on SO about this already](http://www.google.com/search?q=levenshtein+site%3Astackoverflow.com), I suppose you can find some good answers.

Comment: Not really.  He's looking for the fastest way to find the string with the lowest edit distance out of a list of them.

Comment: @Chaos: The fastest way is to look at the edit distance (Levensthein or some other algorithm, doesn't matter here) for every string in the list and then take the first one with the lowest distance. How else would it be done?

Comment: Of course you can short-cut on a perfect match, but that's about it.

Comment: There are definitely faster ways.

Answer (score 1):

You could treat each sequence as an N-dimensional coordinate, chunk the resulting space into blocks that know what sequences occur in them, then on a lookup first search the search sequence's block and all contiguous blocks, then expand outward as necessary.  (Maintaining several scopes of chunking is probably more desirable than getting into searching really large groups of blocks.)

Answer (score 1):

Some variety of [best-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search) on the target sequences will do much better than O(M * N).  The basic idea of this is that you'd compare the first character in your candidate sequence with the first character of the target sequences, then in your second iteration only do the next-character comparison with the sequences that have the least number of mismatches, and so on.  In your first example, you'd wind up comparing against ABCCEFG and AAAAAAA the second time, ABCCEFG only the third and fourth times, all the sequences the fifth time, and only ABCCEFG thereafter.  When you get to the end of your candidate sequence, the set of target sequences with the lowest mismatch count is your match set.

(Note: at each step you're comparing against the next character for *that* branch of the search.  None of the progressive comparisons skip characters.)

Comment: won't work if the you have baaa and abbb as options and look for aaaa. It will throw out the the correct answer in the first iteration.

Comment: Incorrect.  Something like depth-first search would do that; BFS won't.  It won't look at the correct answer on the second iteration, but it will look at it on the third and fourth, and identify it correctly.

Comment: Where you're going wrong is that you're thinking it's throwing things out.  It isn't; it's moving them down a priority queue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between the strings (i.e. the number of different characters at equivalent locations)?

Or does the distance "between" characters (e.g. difference between ASCII values of English letters) matter to you as well?

Comment: +1 Well, upon reading the question again it's more likely to be Hamming than Levensthein.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a general, exact algorithm which will be less than O(N * M), but if you have a small enough M and N you can make an algorithm which performs as (N + M) using bit-parallel operations.

For example, if N and M are both less than 16, you could use a N * M lookup table of 64 bit ints ( 16*log2(16) = 64), and perform all operations in one pass through the string, where each group of 4 bits in the counter counts 0-15 for one of the string being matched. Obviously you need M log2(N+1) bits to store the counters, so might need to update multiple values for each character, but often a single pass lookup can be faster than other approaches. So it's actually O( N * M log(N) ), just with a lower constant factor - using 64 bit ints introduces a 1/64 into it, so should be better if log2(N) < 64. If M log2(N+1) < 64, it works out as (N+M) operations. But that's still linear, rather than sub-linear.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

size_t match ( const char* string, uint64_t table[][128] ) ;

int main ()
{
    const char* data[] = { "ABCCEFG", "AAAAAAA", "TTAGGGT", "ZYXWVUT" };
    const size_t N = 7;
    const size_t M = 4;

    // prepare a table
    uint64_t table[7][128] = { 0 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; ++i )
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j )
            table[j][ (size_t)data[i][j] ] |= 1 << (i * 4);

    const char* examples[] = { "ABCDEFG", "AAAATAA", "TTAGQQT", "ZAAGVUT" };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i ) {
        const char* q = examples[i];
        size_t result = match ( q, table );

        printf("Q(%s) -> %zd %s\n", q, result, data[result]);
    }
}

size_t match ( const char* string, uint64_t table[][128] )
{
    uint64_t count = 0;

    // scan through string once, updating all counters at once
    for ( size_t i = 0; string[i]; ++i )
        count += table[i][ (size_t) string[i] ];

    // find greatest sub-count within count
    size_t best = 0;
    size_t best_sub_count = count & 0xf;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < 4; ++i ) {
        size_t sub_count = ( count >>= 4 ) & 0xf;

        if ( sub_count > best_sub_count ) {
            best_sub_count = sub_count;
            best = i;
        }
    }

    return best;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry for bumping this old thread*

To search elementwise would mean a complexity of O(M*N*N) - O(M) for searching and O(N*N) for calculating levenshtein distance.

The OP is looking for an efficient way to find the smallest hamming distance (c), not the string itself. If you have an upper bound on c (say X), you can find the smallest c in O(log(X)*M*N).

As Stefan pointed out, you can quickly find strings within a given hamming distance. This page http://blog.faroo.com/2015/03/24/fast-approximate-string-matching-with-large-edit-distances/ talks about one such way using Tries. Modify this to just test if there is such a string and binary search on c from 0 to X.

Answer (score -1):

If up front cost don't matter you could calculate the best match for every possible input, and put the result in a hash map.

Of course this won't work if N isn't exremely small.