# string comparison with the most similar string

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, string, comparison

does anyone know if exist an algorithm that given one string A and an array of strings B, compares the A string with all the strings in B giving in output the most similar one.

For "the most similar one" I mean that for example,

if the A string is: "hello world how are you"

then

"asdf asdewr hello world how asfrqr you"

is more similar than:

"h2ll4 w1111 h11 111 111"

Comment: Since you seem to be content with the answers, you can now accept one of them.

Answer (score 21):

The usual measurement for this is the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Compute the Levenshtein distance from the original to each candidate, and take the smallest distance as the most likely candidate.

Comment: Here's a handy dandy link to info about Levenshtein distance. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 14):

Define similarity. Algorithms that can do this include:

1. Levenshtein/LCS/n-gram distance (compare the string with each of the strings in your set, take the one with lowest distance)
2. tf-idf indexing
3. [Levenshtein automata](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata)
4. [Hopfield networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_net)
5. [BK-trees](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees)

All of which can feasibly by implemented in C or C++. Google "string similarity", "duplicate finding" or "record linkage" for the available metrics and algorithms.

Comment: I think before starting to choose the algorithm it's better to define in a proper manner the similarity, you're right. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is usually done with checking a bunch of variations of the string that you have ... take a look at spelling correction algorithms - e.g. [here](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)