# C++ String Comparisons

Tags: c++, arrays, string, character, delimiter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [string comparison with the most similar string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861718/string-comparison-with-the-most-similar-string)

I was wondering what the best way to go about comparing two strings for (For a certain percentage of) similarity is. EX: String 1 is "I really like to eat pie," and String 2 is "I really like to eat cheese," with a function returning "true" because more than 50% of the characters are similar.

I was thinking that I could see if each character in one string is somewhere in the other, but there's probably a more precise way to go about things. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

[Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) might be suitable. It tells how many single-character insertions, deletions or replacements must be made in order to transform one string into the other. You can also give different priorities to the three operations.

Comment: Indeed, see the duplicate question I linked.

Answer (score 0):

For a fuzzy compare like this you could split each string up into words (using strtok()) and compare the two word arrays case-insensitive using stricmp().  There is also the SOUNDEX algorithm to compare words to see if they sound the same.