# Efficient Way to find most similar value

Tags: java, string, similarity

I have a value such as Color, and a list of String : {Colour,Color,Main Color, Main Colour, Theme, Brand, Subject ..... etc}

I would like to get the most similar string , except the searched string itself. In this example would expect to get Colour. (NOT Color)

I am sorting the list
I am using the following rules and ranked the rules :

1. Filter the same value
2. check upper lower cases
3. delete whitespaces. trim
4. using Levenshtein distance
5. String order : Main color = Color Main
6. check for acronym : HP - Hewlett Packard

It takes a lot of time to go over a list of 1000 relevant candidates. Moreover I have lots of candidates to check.

Any other efficient way?

Original Code:

```
public static List findSimilarity(String word, List candidates) {
    List recommendations = new ArrayList();
    if (!word.equals("")) {
        for (String candidate : candidates) {
            if (!word.equals(candidate)) { //1. same token , lower/upper cases , ignore white spaces
                if (StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(word).equalsIgnoreCase(StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(candidate))) {
                    recommendations.add(candidate);
                }
                //2. same tokens diff order
                else if (candidate.split(" ").length == word.split("     ").length) {
                    String[] candidatearr = candidate.split(" ");
                    String[] wordarr = word.split(" ");
                    boolean status = true;
                    SortIgnoreCase icc = new SortIgnoreCase();
                    Arrays.sort(candidatearr, icc);
                    Arrays.sort(wordarr, icc);
                    for (int i = 0; i < candidatearr.length; i++) {
                        if (!(candidatearr[i] == null ? wordarr[i] == null : wordarr[i].equalsIgnoreCase(candidatearr[i])))
                            status = false;
                    }

                    if (status) {
                        recommendations.add(candidate);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //3. distance between words
        if (recommendations.size() == 0) {
            for (String candidate : candidates) {
                if (!word.equals(candidate)) {
                    String[] candidatearr = candidate.split(" ");
                    String[] wordarr = word.split(" ");
                    //check for acronym
                    if ((wordarr.length == 1 && candidatearr.length > 1) || (wordarr.length > 1 && candidatearr.length == 1)) {
                        String acronym = "";
                        if (wordarr.length > candidatearr.length) {
                            for (String tmp : wordarr) {
                                if (!tmp.equals("")) {
                                    acronym = acronym + tmp.substring(0, 1);
                                }
                            }

                            if (acronym.equalsIgnoreCase(candidatearr[0])) {
                                recommendations.add(candidate);
                            }
                        } else {
                            for (String tmp : candidatearr) {
                                if (!tmp.equals("")) {
                                    acronym = acronym + tmp.substring(0, 1);
                                }
                            }

                            if (acronym.equalsIgnoreCase(wordarr[0])) {
                                recommendations.add(candidate);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (recommendations.size() == 0) {
            for (String candidate : candidates) {
                if (!word.equals(candidate)) {
                    int dist = 0;
                    String check = "";
                    if (word.length() > candidate.length()) {
                        check = candidate;
                    } else {
                        check = word;
                    }
                    if (check.length() <= 3) {
                        dist = 0;
                    } else if (check.length() > 3 && check.length() <= 5) {
                        dist = 1;
                    } else if (check.length() > 5) {
                        dist = 2;
                    }

                    if (StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(word, candidate) <= dist) {
                        //if(Levenshtein.distance(word,candidate) <= dist){
                        recommendations.add(candidate);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (recommendations.size() == 0) {
            for (String candidate : candidates) {
                if (!word.equals(candidate)) {
                    String[] candidatearr = candidate.split(" ");
                    String[] wordarr = word.split(" ");

                    for (String cand : candidatearr) {
                        for (String wor : wordarr) {
                            if (cand.equals(wor) && cand.length() > 4) {
                                recommendations.add(candidate);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }//for
            if (recommendations.size() > 4) {
                recommendations.clear();
            }
        }

        //4. low priority - starts with
        if (recommendations.size() == 0) {
            for (String candidate : candidates) {
                if (!word.equals(candidate)) {
                    if (candidate.startsWith(word) || word.startsWith(candidate)) {
                        recommendations.add(candidate);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (recommendations.size() > 4) {
                recommendations.clear();
            }
        }

        //5. low priority - contain word
        if (recommendations.size() == 0) {
            for (String candidate : candidates) {
                if (!word.equals(candidate)) {
                    if (candidate.contains(word) || word.contains(candidate)) {
                        recommendations.add(candidate);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (recommendations.size() > 4) {
                recommendations.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    return recommendations;
}
```

Thanks,
M.

Comment: you could make use of soundex  which is provided by apache for example.

Comment: @KevinEsche he named sorting by Levenshtein distance, this is what apache StringUtils implement

Comment: Your case looks like a good candidate for using Java 8 streams chained with filters. For computation efficiency, you can parallelise the processing. Do you want to see an example?

Comment: @nolexa I would appreciate to see an example. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinEsche I was wrong. Levenshtein distance and soundex difference are two separate things, both implemented by Apache though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string comparison with the most similar string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861718/string-comparison-with-the-most-similar-string)

Comment: Could you please add your original code to your question? The one that you're not happy about. This will help to understand your problem. You're asking about any other efficient way, but not showing what is the current solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

I wrapped the answer given by Bohemian into the context of your original code for your better understanding.

The line `.map(term -> Arrays.stream(term.split(" ")).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))` splits multi-word terms, sorts, and joins again to eliminate permutations of same words. This is an answer to the permutational equality challenge of terms like "main color" and "color main".

However, it does not make sense to catch all the business requirements of your task in the context of this question. By this answer you have got an outline of the solution. The problem of efficiency is addressed. You might need more stages in your pipeline, but that's a different story. The strength of the approach is that all stages are detached, so you can ask questions and seek help for each stage independently.

```
public static String findSimilarity(String word, List<String> candidatesList) {

    // Populating the set with distinct values of the input terms
    Set<String> candidates = candidatesList.stream()
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .map(term -> Arrays.stream(term.split(" ")).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(" "))) // eliminates permutations
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    Map<String, Integer> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    return candidates.parallelStream()
            .map(String::trim)
                    // add more mappers if needed
            .filter(s -> !s.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
                    // add more filters if needed
            .min((a, b) -> Integer.compare(
                    cache.computeIfAbsent(a, k -> getLevenshteinDistance(word, k)),
                    cache.computeIfAbsent(b, k -> getLevenshteinDistance(word, k))))
            .get(); // get the closest match
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But the acronyms are randomly, I don't have a close list. 
I split the string to words by " " delimiter and take the first char.
Moreover the code doesn't answer request 5. Check the order of the string .

Comment: Of course the source does not have to be a close list. I just followed your sample. If you split an input string, you can do `Stream.of(input.split(" "))`. Can you elaborate on the request 5? How do you want to sort the strings exactly?

Comment: Could you please add it to the code?
1. I want to take the given String for example : Brand Compatible, and check if in the sortedlist there exists "Compatible Brand"
2. I want to take the given string "Brand Compatible" and check if in the sortedlist there exists "BC" (the acronyms)
Thank you!

Comment: Firstly, I don't understand what is the criteria of the check. Is that having same words in different permutations? You only give one example. Secondly, I don't understand what do you want to do after checking the condition. Suppose you have both "Compatible Brand" and "Brand Compatible", what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Yes. I want to check if the same tokens exist in different order in some strings than recommends on them as similar strings. Such as : Main Color  will be recommended for Color Main . Brand Compatible will be recommended for Compatible Brand. Different permutations will be recommended as similar strings.

Comment: What is the desired outcome in the resulting list of strings? Could you explain this in terms of filtering and/or sorting? What's going to happen with the two strings "Main Color" and "Color Main"? I don't understand the term "recommended".

Comment: I have a db which contains similar strings, duplicate strings and I want to create single value for each token. So Comatible Brand is same as Brand Compatible and I want to recommend it for merge tokens. color or colour are same , Color or color are same. I post my original code above. Thanks

Comment: Now I see what you mean. You want to ignore some elements of your input list because of their permutational equality to some other elements. You can do this the way Bohemian suggested in his answer, by lowercasing, sorting words in the same order, and putting them into a `Set`. All values will be distinct before you start the pipeline processing.

Comment: Please create a new question for that. The spirit of Stackoverflow is one problem per question. This way answers can be useful to a lot of people, not just for the one who asked. Your initial problem has been addressed. Just make a new question and you will get a lot of help.

Comment: How do I define the minimum distance from getLevenshteinDistance function?
If the distance if greater than 2 , I don't want to return this value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101588/discussion-between-nolexa-and-userit1985).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is one of time complexity. Collections.sort() is an O(n log n) operation, and this is how many times the compare method is called. The problem is that Levenshtein is an "expensive" calculation.

You can improve sorting performance by finding a way to calculate it exactly once for each item making the Levenshtein calculation an O(n), operation, then sorting on the stored calculated distance.

I did a test using a variety of list sizes sorting Lists of random integers, and the actual number of times `compare()` was called was very close to n log<sub>2</sub> n, so for a list of about 1000 Strings, it will be about 10 times faster, because log<sub>2</sub>(1000) is about 10.

You can further improve performance by **not sorting**, but by just getting the *minimum* item specifying the same comparator.

Another improvement is to avoid the `distinct()` call (which is relatively expensive), by using Set (which enforces uniqueness) to hold the candidates.

If you can, populate the candidates with values *already* trained and lowercased, so you avoid trimming and lowercasing and lowercase every run. Do the same your input, so you can use `equals()` instead of the slower `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

Here's one way:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance;

String search; // your input
Set<String> candidates = new HashSet<>(); // populate this with lots of values
Map<String, Integer> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
String closest = candidates.parallelStream()
    .map(String::trim)
    .filter(s -> !s.equalsIgnoreCase(search))
    .min((a, b) -> Integer.compare(
      cache.computeIfAbsent(a, k -> getLevenshteinDistance(search, k)),
      cache.computeIfAbsent(b, k -> getLevenshteinDistance(search, k))))
    .get();
```

This code executes in about 50ms for 1000 random candidates, and in about 1 second for 1 million candidates.

Comment: I get an error :the type HashCode is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Comment: @userit1985 It should have been `HashSet`. See edited version. I just thumbed this in on the train, so there could be other typos too. Do you know how to populate a Set with your value?

Comment: I still get error on 'computeIfAbsent'
I generated the Set in this way: Set<String> candidates = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList
    ("Main Color", "color" , "Theme","Color","Main Colour","Colour")); // populate this with lots of values

Comment: @userit1985 I have fixed the minor syntax error. When tested with a million random candidate strings, this code executes in 700ms and with 1000 candidates in 50ms

Comment: Great ! but the code is not answering conditions 5 & 6.
String order : Main color = Color Main
check for acronym : HP - Hewlett Packard
Moreover the acronym is randomly, I don't have a close list.

Comment: @userit1985 you haven't shown any code relating to those criteria, or defined exactly how they should work, so I don't know what you mean. The only clue you posted to slowness was "sorting", so that's what I answered. Basically the problem was sorting using a comparator. Those extra criteria are irrelevant to the time complexity. Ask another question to get help with how to implement those last too criteria - including them here makes the question too broad.