# Algorithm for searching the database

Tags: database, string, algorithm, search, search-engine

I have a database of about 15000 entries and I would like to implement a search algorithm for the fronted part of the application, but I don't know how I should start. 
The search algorithm should rank the search results and should accept errors in writing.
Example:
If I search "Pordlnd" it should give me "Portland" as a result.

Also it should not care about the string length.
Example:
If I search "new" both "New York" and "New Hampshire" should have the same rank as they both contain the word "new".

I would like to write it myself, more as an exercise so if you could point me in the right direction your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called approximate/fuzzy string search. This is a really vast topic, with a lot of different implementations, but one of my favorite beginner tutorials was: https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html (Note that this doesn't exactly conform to your requirements, but is a good read nonetheless).

At it's core your problem boils down to: Give a score of say 0 - 1 to all the words in your dictionary, based on some match criteria, and return the top N entries based on that score. (Of course, you'll have to be clever on how to compute this as this takes a lot of processing power).

Here is some intro on how to give that score:
Edit Distance/Levenstein Distance gives you the "minimum cost" to convert one string to another using insertions/deletions/substitutions of characters. You can check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance or this Youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xxx0b7djCrs . You might want to use deletion cost of a character to be 0, because you want New York/New Hampshire to have the same rank when you search for New. Here's a little youtube video on how to use Levenstein Distance with BK Trees: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIsPB2pqq_8 .

Cosine distance is another measure of similarity between 2 vectors, and here's a good explanation: https://blog.nishtahir.com/2015/09/19/fuzzy-string-matching-using-cosine-similarity/

After a little googling, here's an old SO answer: [Fastest way to find most similar string to an input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643538/fastest-way-to-find-most-similar-string-to-an-input)